# An array of function values over the region $\{(x,y): -1\le x,y\le 1\}$

Tags: list-manipulation, grid-layouts

I had one of my colleague instructors ask me how to evaluate the function $f(x,y)=x^2+2y^2-x$ over a few points in the region $\{(x,y): -1\le x,y\le 1\}$ and display them in table form with headings that indicate the coordinates of the points at which the evaluations of the function takes place.

I came up with a fairly crude idea.

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + 2 y^2 - x
data = Transpose[
   Round[Array[f, {11, 11}, {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}}], 0.01]];
TableForm[data, 
 TableHeadings -> {{"-1", "-0.8", "-0.6", -"0.4", "-0.2", "0.0", 
    "0.2", "0.4", "0.6", "0.8", "1.0"}, {"-1", "-0.8", "-0.6", -"0.4",
     "-0.2", "0.0", "0.2", "0.4", "0.6", "0.8", "1.0"}}]
```

Which produced this result.

[image]

Could any of my colleagues share a cleaner idea? Thanks.

**Update:** Due to the hints from my colleagues, here is what I'll share with my fellow instructor.

```
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + 2 y^2 - x
data = Transpose[
   Round[Array[f, {11, 11}, {{-1, 1}, {1, -1}}], 0.01]];
TableForm[data, 
 TableHeadings -> {Range[-1, 1, 0.2], Range[-1, 1, 0.2]}, 
 TableAlignments -> "."]
```

Comment: Instead of manually writing the `TableHeadings`, you can use `Range[-1, 1, 0.2]`.

Comment: You could use `TableHeadings -> ConstantArray[Range[-1, 1, .2], 2]` instead of the list of headings.

Comment: `TableAlignments -> "."` might be a nice option to add.

Comment: Somewhat nicer looking: `Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]`

Comment: All, thanks for the hints. `I've posted the final result in my original post.